# strange "not defined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the below code in my viewmodel:

```
CA = function (clientNum) {
    this.CAName = null;
    this.CAAdress = null;
    this.CAIdNum = null;
    this.CAContact = null;
    this.CANote = null;
    this.CAType = null;
    this.clNum = clientNum;
},
viewModelNewCredit = function () {
    var
    creditRows = ko.observableArray(),
        showView = ko.observable(),
        sessionTicket = ko.observable(),
        loggedUser = ko.observable()
        newCreditRows = function () {
            console.log(this.clientNum());
            this.creditRows.push(new CA(this.clientNum()));
            console.log(creditRows());
        },

        remove = function (ca) {
            this.creditRows.remove(ca);
        };
    return {
        creditRows: creditRows,
        showView: showView,
        sessionTicket: sessionTicket,
        loggedUser: loggedUser,
        viewModelNewCredit: viewModelNewCredit,
        remove: remove
    };
},
```

And In my HTML I have:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: creditRows">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="CAType" id="CAType" data-bind="value: CAType" style="width: 8em;">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CAName" id="CAName" data-bind="value: CAName" style="width: 15em;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CAAdress" data-bind="value: CAAdress" style="width: 15em;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CAIdNum" data-bind="value: CAIdNum" style="width: 6em;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CAContact" data-bind="value: CAContact" style="width: 10em;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CANote" data-bind="value: CANote" style="width: 15em;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="/projMonitoring/js/images/close.jpg" alt="Close" data-bind="click: remove.bind($parent)">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="newRow" class="button" data-bind="click: newCreditRows">Add new row</button>
<button type="button" id="OpenModal" class="button" data-bind="click: openModal">Open Modal</button>
```

This line of code:
`<img src="/projMonitoring/js/images/close.jpg" alt="Close" data-bind="click: remove.bind($parent)">`
is supposed to execute a function, but what I'm getting is:

> Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: remove is not defined; Bindings value: click: remove.bind($parent)

do you have an idea what is going on? I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something really small, but I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: as it says... `remove` is not defined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the context of a foreach, so when you are calling the remove method, you are trying to call it on the element from the array you are traversing. instead you need to call it on the ViewModel:

```
<img src="/projMonitoring/js/images/close.jpg" alt="Close" data-bind="click: $root.remove">
```

Comment: ok, but what I got now is: `TypeError: this.creditRows is undefined` :(

Comment: log the `this` and see what it refers to, my guess, it's the window scope. try encapsulating `this` by adding to the beginning of you VM constructor: `var self = this ` and then use `self` instead

Comment: found teh solution! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an instance of your view model. Change your binding the following way:

```
var x = new viewModelNewCredit();
ko.applyBindings(x);
```

Somewhat approximated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gE3a7/.